# Using circular FK references in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have two (mysql) tables -- `company` and `user`. They are structured as follows:

```
`user`
- id
- company_id (FK to company)
- name

`company`
- id
- name
- admin_user_id (FK to user)
```

The `user` table foreign keys to the `company` table, and vice versa.

I was wondering if the above pattern is ok, and if it's not why it's not, what could be done to improve it.

Comment: You can define a composite FK (admin_user_id, id) of company table to (id, company_id) of user table. This would ensure that "admin user" in the user table has same company_id , as it is defined in the admin_user_id of company table. This would ensure data integrity

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya that makes sense conceptually, but would you be able to show that in an answer perhaps to show how that would be done?

Comment: *Gordon Linoff's* answer is pretty much same on what I am suggesting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high level, your data model makes sense.  However, you have no guarantee that `admin_user_id` points to a `user` in the same company.  You can solve this by doing:

```
create table users (
    user_id int auto_increment primary key,
    company_id int,
    name varchar(255),
    unique (company_id, user_id)  -- redundant but desirable for the foreign key reference
);

create table companies (
    company_id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    admin_user_id int,
    foreign key (company_id, admin_user_id) references users(company_id, user_id)
);

alter table users
    add constraint fk_users_company_id
        foreign key (company_id) references companies (company_id);
```

Comment: thanks, yes this is what I currently have actually. In the above you've just explicitly defined not only the FKs but also how to add these in, which is also a big help

Answer (score 3):

If it is an accurate representation of your business domain then that's what really matters. There is a possible problem in SQL however. SQL only allows one table to be updated at once so either company or user has to come first. Normally you have to allow the constraint to be broken temporarily, either when you insert a new company with no corresponding user, or insert a new user with no corresponding company. To achieve that you can make one of the foreign keys nullable or you can temporarily disable the constraint.

Some data modellers dislike circular dependencies, even in purely conceptual models where the limitations of SQL are irrelevant. A few people will perceive circular dependencies as a modelling mistake - wrongly in my opinion. Disapproval of circular dependencies seems to be associated with ER modelling specifically. Interestingly, circular self-referential dependencies are taken for granted in Object Role Modelling which even has a special notation for them (ring constraints).

Comment: in the case where some people would want to do it different, how would they do it differently? Would they have a separate table for `CompanyAdmin` or something similar?